# Creating more extensible data extraction from json files

Tags: python, pandas

I am looping through a large number of Json files extracting data into variables before putting the data to a dataframe.  Something like this:

```
    fullTimeEmployees = financial_data['fullTimeEmployees']
    longBusinessSummary = financial_data['longBusinessSummary']
    currentRatio = data['quoteSummary']['result'][0]['financialData']['currentRatio']['raw']
    datarow = [fullTimeEmployees,longBusinessSummary,currentRatio]
    output_data.append(datarow)
```

df = pd.DataFrame(output_data, columns =['fullTimeEmployees', 'longBusinessSummary', 'currentRatio',,,,,,

Is there a more efficient was of doing this in a loop and config?  Ideally allowing me to put better error trapping around it and also add data fields more easily.

An example JSON dataset is here:
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/1109.HK?formatted=true&crumb=cmEFpzsN8.l&lang=en-CA&region=CA&modules=defaultKeyStatistics%2CsummaryProfile%2CassetProfile%2CincomeStatementHistory%2CincomeStatementHistoryQuarterly%2CbalanceSheetHistory%2CbalanceSheetHistoryQuarterly%2CcashflowStatementHistory%2CcashflowStatementHistoryQuarterly%2CdefaultKeyStatistics%2CfinancialData%2CcalendarEvents%2CsecFilings%2CrecommendationTrend%2CupgradeDowngradeHistory%2CinstitutionOwnership%2CfundOwnership%2CmajorDirectHolders%2CmajorHoldersBreakdown%2CinsiderTransactions%2CinsiderHolders%2CnetSharePurchaseActivity%2Cearnings%2CearningsHistory%2CearningsTrend%2CindustryTrend%2CindexTrend%2CsectorTrend&corsDomain=ca.finance.yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request
import json

url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/1109.HK?formatted=true&crumb=cmEFpzsN8.l&lang=en-CA&region=CA&modules=defaultKeyStatistics%2CsummaryProfile%2CassetProfile%2CincomeStatementHistory%2CincomeStatementHistoryQuarterly%2CbalanceSheetHistory%2CbalanceSheetHistoryQuarterly%2CcashflowStatementHistory%2CcashflowStatementHistoryQuarterly%2CdefaultKeyStatistics%2CfinancialData%2CcalendarEvents%2CsecFilings%2CrecommendationTrend%2CupgradeDowngradeHistory%2CinstitutionOwnership%2CfundOwnership%2CmajorDirectHolders%2CmajorHoldersBreakdown%2CinsiderTransactions%2CinsiderHolders%2CnetSharePurchaseActivity%2Cearnings%2CearningsHistory%2CearningsTrend%2CindustryTrend%2CindexTrend%2CsectorTrend&corsDomain=ca.finance.yahoo.com'
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as res:
  json_data = json.loads(res.read().decode('utf-8'))

asset = json_data['quoteSummary']['result'][0]['assetProfile']
trend = json_data['quoteSummary']['result'][0]['recommendationTrend']
cashf = json_data['quoteSummary']['result'][0]['cashflowStatementHistory']

print(asset['address1'])

for t in trend['trend']:
  print(t['period'], t['strongBuy'], t['buy'], t['hold'], t['sell'], t['strongSell'])

for c in cashf['cashflowStatements']:
  print(f"Cash flow: {c['endDate']['raw']} - {c['endDate']['fmt']}")
  print(f"Net Income: {c['netIncome']['raw']}")
```

The output:

```
China Resources Building
0m 0 0 0 0 0
-1m 6 18 1 0 0
-2m 6 20 1 0 0
-3m 7 20 0 0 0
Cash flow: 1514678400 - 2017-12-31
Net Income: 23016685000
Cash flow: 1483142400 - 2016-12-31
Net Income: 19500880000
Cash flow: 1451520000 - 2015-12-31
Net Income: 17697752000
Cash flow: 1419984000 - 2014-12-31
Net Income: 15140938000
```

Comment: Yes, that works for one stock, next I am running through a list of tickers = ['0494.HK','0101.HK','0980.HK','BNS.TO','BMO.TO','OBE.TO'].  Some don't have data for one of the items which breaks the code.  I started to write try/expect blocks for each data item.  But the code is becoming very cumbersome.

Comment: You can use `if "address1" in json_data` to check the existence key in json data.